# Probability with replacement

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm having trouble figuring out this probability problem. I've tried multiplying the probabilities together, but I don't think its right.

An urn contains one white and four black balls. If five balls are selected with replacement, 
what is the probability of selecting at least one white ball.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event of obtaining all $5$ black balls, and $A'$ be the complementary event of A. We find $P(A')$. We have :$P(A) = (\dfrac{4}{5})^5$. So $P(A') = 1 - P(A) = 1 - (\dfrac{4}{5})^5$.